# Embed Angular 5 App in another in Jsp Project

Tags: java, angular, jsp, angular5

I have an Angular 5 application, customers have asked me to include it in two applications (C # and Jsp), possibly without using IFrame. it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "include" it without using some kind of iframes. What you could do though, is use a web server (apache or nginx) to give the users the impression that they're on the same website.

Let's say for example that the C# web application runs on IIS on port 1234, and that the Java application runs on Tomcat on port 4321, the web-server can act as a reverse proxy. Every request made to "mysite.com/app1" goes to the first one, and requests to "mysite.com/app2" goes to the second one.

Then you just have to define a third url, "mysite.com/app3" for your Angular application.

You could achieve the same result using subdomains if you wish (app1.mysite.com).